# log4j different levels of details

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j 1.2 and I want to achieve the following behaviour:

I want to be able to log from all classes in the package. The log should be written in a detailed version (including info and debug messages) to a file, but I want to receive a short version (errors and fatals) as String.

From the documentation I guessed that I probably have to define two different logger instances which are ancestors or each other and assign appenders to them. But I neither know the details nor do I know if this is the intended way to achieve this behaviour.

Can somebody please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define only one logger which you affect two file appenders: one with level error and the other with the debug level. The level filtering will be done in the appender.

```
<appender name="DebugAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/debug.log" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB" />
    <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %t %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ErrorAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/error.log" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB" />
    <param name="threshold" value="error" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %t %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="mylogger">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorAppender" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Is it possible to append directly to a String (StringBuffer, StringBuilder,...) instead of writing to a file and reading this back?

Comment: @JFMeier It should be possible but i think you need to develop a custom appender.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the same logger and just apply a filter to the handlers, i.e. set the log level for the console handler (which I assume you mean with "as String") to `ERROR`.